# Select top 2 sold products for each month in each department

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return for **each** `department`, the **top 2** sold products of **each** `month`, in the year 2016.

My database has the following structure:

```
Sales(Time_id: Date, Geo_id: char(5), Prod_id: char(6), sales: Int)
Time(Time_id: Date, month: char(2), quarter: char(1), year: char(4))
Geo(Geo_id: char(5), city: varchar(20), dept: char(2), region: char(2))
Product(Prod_id: char(6), class: char(2), category: char(2))
```

I'm using OracleSQL.

Here's what I've done so far, for some reason I keep getting "not a GROUP BY expression":

```sql
SELECT
    t.dep, t.month, t.prod, t.sales
FROM (
    SELECT
        Geo.dept AS dep, Time.month AS month, Sales.Prod_id AS prod, SUM(Sales.sales) AS sales,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Geo.dept ORDER BY SUM(Sales.sales) DESC NULLS LAST) AS rank
    FROM
        Sales
    INNER JOIN
        Time ON Sales.Time_id = Time.Time_id
    INNER JOIN
        Geo ON Sales.Geo_id = Geo.Geo_id
) t 
WHERE
    t.rank <= 2
GROUP BY
    t.month
```

As for the returned values, I just want the records to state the `department`, the `month`, the `product ID` and the `number of sales`.

Comment: produce a [mre] basically when you group by all select cpolumn have to be in the GROUP BY or ise an aggregation function

Comment: "not a GROUP BY expression" is an Oracle error (not T-SQL) and indicates you are missing some columns in the `group by`, which you are. And is there any particular reason you are using `,` join syntax, which was deprecated 30 years ago? Also are you sure you want `RANK()` and not `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: @Charlieface I edited my post for the join syntax. I'm using `RANK()` as I'm not sure if I have duplicate values in my database. I tried removing the `t.prod` column value from my statement, and grouped by `t.dep, t.month` to leave only the aggregate function, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` should be in the inner query not the outer, as that is where the aggregation by `month` is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-aggregated columns have to be part of the `GROUP BY` clause; therefore, as commented it should be moved into the subquery. Also, you *forgot* to include the `year = 2016` condition.

```
SELECT
    t.dep,
    t.month,
    t.prod,
    t.sales
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            geo.dept         AS dep,
            time.month       AS month,
            sales.prod_id    AS prod,
            SUM(sales.sales) AS sales,
            RANK()
            OVER(PARTITION BY geo.dept, time.month
                 ORDER BY
                     SUM(sales.sales) DESC NULLS LAST
            )                AS rank
        FROM
                 sales
            INNER JOIN time ON sales.time_id = time.time_id
            INNER JOIN geo ON sales.geo_id = geo.geo_id
        WHERE
            time.year = 2016
        GROUP BY
            geo.dept,
            time.month,
            sales.prod_id
    ) t
WHERE
    t.rank <= 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm clearly misunderstanding `GROUP BY` clauses. One thing I would add that potentially solved the problem, is that I changed the partitioning to `PARTITION BY geo.dept, time.month`.

Comment: You're welcome. If modified PARTITION BY returned what you wanted, even better; I'm glad you fixed it.